# Is this equation expected to be a plane? How can I get some better intuition?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

In 2 dimensions $Y=cX+B$ is a line. In 3D $Z=aY+bX+C$ is a plane...

But this won't be a line: $f(x)=1/(1+e^-5x)$.

And how is this a plane?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a plane. The graph looks like a plane because it was drawn with $(x,y)\in\left[-\frac12,\frac12\right]\times\left[-\frac12,\frac12\right]$. If you choose $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ instead, then you will get this:

[image]

Comment: yes, i should choose -1 1 i believe. thanks!